# this.route in RouterService is not having correct url

Tags: angular

I was trying to write an function in my `RouterService` to add query params.
here is my Router Service

```
export class RouterService {
  constructor(
    private router : Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  addQueryParams(params : {}){
    debugger;
    console.log(this.route.toString());
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: params,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      skipLocationChange: true
    });
  }
}
```

add here is my component where i am using this function.

```
navegateRole(){
  this.routerService.addQueryParams({id : "2"});
}
```

Now, in my RouterService this.route is not giving me the current active `http://localhost:4200/core/enterpriseprofile`. Its giving this `Route(url:'', path:'')`empty object.

Comment: I think you need `this.router.url`. This will give you `/core/enterpriseprofile` and this can be used to navigate.

Comment: ya but my question is why is ```this.route``` giving ```Route(url:'', path:'')``` as output instead of ```/core/enterpriseprofile```

Comment: I honestly can't say for sure, try to do a console.log of the `activated route` before you call `this.routerService.addQueryParams()`. If there is a valid route object then I guess you will have to provide the service in your component (so it will create an instance of route when the component is created and the route is correct)

Comment: NO ,I am more interested in why its not working than finding a work-around .why is this.route giving Route(url:'', path:'')  instead of current active route

Comment: As I said, do a console.log before calling the service! I tested something and if my service is provided in the module, activated route is undefined inside it. If my service is provided in the component it gives the correct activated route. So.. where are you providing your service?

Answer (score 0):

`this.route` in your code represents [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute). To fetch url from the same, you can use [`url`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#url) property of ActivatedRoute.

As `url` property is Observable, you would need to perform some operation on it to fetch it as string, for example:

```
const url: Observable<string> = this.route.url.pipe(map(segments => segments.join('/')));
```

Now, you can subscribe to `url` like below to get relative url:

```
this.url.subscribe(value=>{
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: ```this.router.navigate``` function's argument  ```relativeTo``` takes an object of type   ```ActivatedRoute``` not a string.
 Anyway 
```const url: Observable<string> = this.route.url.map( segments => segments.join(''));```
will return an empty string not ```http://localhost:4200/core/enterpriseprofile``` as desired

Comment: @shoaibsiddiquie Sorry, I didn't get what you tried to mention in your comment. You haven't asked anything related to router.navigate function. And url won't return an empty string, when you subscribe to it, it will return relative url. I will update my answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the current route you have to use `this.router.url`

For more options check the `window.location` object. This will give you plenty of options to work with.

*Example*

```
window.location.
      hash: "#/core/enterpriseprofile"
      host: "localhost:4200"
      hostname: "localhost"
      href: "http://localhost:4200/#/core/enterpriseprofile"
      origin: "http://localhost:4200"
      pathname: "/"
      port: "4200"
      protocol: "http:"
```

[window.location docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: No but my question is why is this.route giving Route(url:'', path:'') as output instead of /core/enterpriseprofile in RouterService